# Invariance of subgroups using the mapping of an isotypical decomposition in representation theory

Tags: representation-theory, invariance

I was presented with this question as a study problem in my representation theory course in college and have spent hours trying to solve it or find something similar. Any help or direction on this problem would be greatly appreciated

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ ($gHg^{-1} =H$ for all $g \in G$). Let $P^h_v: G → GL(V)$ be a representation
of $G$. Let $\rho^H_v: H \to G \to GL(V)$ be the restriction of the representation to $H$.
Let $V = \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^n W_i$
be the isotypical decomposition of $V$.
 Prove that for any $g \in G$ and $i \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ there is a $j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$ such that $g(W_i) = W_j$ and $(g\cdot h)(W_i) = W_j$ for any $h \in H$

Comment: Unreadable in my browser.

Comment: This is what your question looks like: https://imgur.com/a/cAaiW

Comment: Do you mean the isotypical decomposition of $V$ into $H$ modules?

Comment: Hi sorry, I was not familiar with how the formatting of symbols worked on this site. Thank you, @JonathanDunay for the help on that. The way that the question was presented to us was that V was isotypically decomposed into irreducible representations of general elements $ W_i $ it was not mentioned whether or not they where H modules or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: show that if $U$ is an irreducible $H$ module and $g \in G$, then $gU$ is also an irreducible $H$ module and if $U_1 \cong U_2$ are isomorphic as $H$ modules, then $gU_1 \cong gU_2$ are also isomorphic as $H$ modules. Use this to show that isotypic components must go to isotypic components as the problem asks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help @JonathanDunay. Just wondering what is U, is it just an arbitrary irreducible element of H or is it a value from the isotypical decomposition V that is also in the subset H.

Comment: $U$ would be a submodule of one of the isotypic components. If you like, you can think of each of the isotypic components as being written as $W_i = \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i=1}^n U_{i,j}$ where for each $i$, the $U_{i,j}$ are isomorphic as $H$ modules and are irreducible.

Comment: For this problem, we were told to assume that V was being decomposed into irreducible elements, thus I am uncertain as to how you are decomposing each isotypic component further.

Comment: The isotypic components are not themselves defined to be irreducible but, are a direct sum of irreducible, isomorphic representations. By definition, if $V$ is a representation, and $U$ is an irreducible representation, then the isotypic component of $U$, $IC(U)$ is the sum of all submodules of $V$ isomorphic to $U$.